# validation in p2p communication

Tags: networking, encryption, hash, p2p

Suppose that in my "network" of users each node can create only one hashed code (generated with the node's id).

Now, node A sends to node B this hashed code. node A is no longer the owner, but B is. 
still, it's just a string, so node A decide to trick the system and sends also to node C the same code. how can node C know that A made an illegal operation?

can C validate the operation only by communicating with node A? (without server or communication with other nodes)

thanks

Comment: I recommend using Ed25519 for that. It has nice small 32 byte public keys, is very fast for an asymmetric scheme, and with a few tricks it can be used for both key-exchange and signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your question is:

> How can I prevent node id theft/forgery in a p2p overlay network?

The answer is:

By use of public key cryptography.

Comment: can you explain a bit more how can it be used?